# OSMF how to get screenshot

Tags: apache-flex, screenshot, osmf

in normal screenshot like this:
bitmapData.draw(video, new Matrix());
but how to get video object in osmf player? I've tried draw mediaPlayerSprite result in a blank image

```
var pictureData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height); 
var x:DisplayObjectTrait = _mediaPlayer.media.getTrait(org.osmf.traits.MediaTraitType.DISPLAY_OBJECT) as DisplayObjectTrait; 
var y:Video = x.displayObject as Video; 
pictureData.draw(m_container, new Matrix());  
var byteArray:ByteArray = new JPEGEncoder(80).encode(pictureData);  
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();  
file.save(byteArray, "pic.jpeg");
```

Comment: `var pictureData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height);
var x:DisplayObjectTrait = m_mediaPlayer.media.getTrait(org.osmf.traits.MediaTraitType.DISPLAY_OBJECT) as DisplayObjectTrait;
var y:Video = x.displayObject as Video;pictureData.draw(m_container, new Matrix());
var byteArray:ByteArray = new JPEGEncoder(80).encode(pictureData);
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
file.save(byteArray, "pic.jpeg");`

Answer (score 0):

To get the Bitmapdata from the video:

```
var videoDisplay:VideoDisplay = video.videoDisplay;
var videoObject:Video = videoDisplay.videoObject;
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoObject.videoWidth, videoObject.videoHeight, true, 0x000000);
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but i just wander how to get the video from osmf(as mediaPlayer, mediaContainer),could you give more code plz? thank you again:)

Comment: Could you edit your question with the relevant code you already have, I don't think I understand your problem. So if you could elaborate on that aswell, that will allow me to help you more.

Comment: I've added comment with code. the way i get video object should be wrong, could you post the right way?